# Can you refer to and filter on a script field in a query expression, after defining it?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch and was wondering, once you define a script field with mvel syntax, can you subsequently filter on, or refer to it in the query body as if it was any other field?

I can't find any examples of this while same time I don't see any mention of whether this is possible on the docs page

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/scripting/
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields/

The book ElasticSearch Server doesn't mention if this is possible or not either

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible for one simple reason: the script_fields are calculated during final stage of search (fetch phase) and only for the records that you retrieve (top 10 by default). The script filter is applied to all records that were not filtered out by preceding filters and it happens during query phase, which precedes the fetch phase. In other words, when filters are applied the script_fields don't exist yet.

Answer (score 15):

As for 2018 and Elastic 6.2 it is still not possible to filter by fields defined with `script_fields`, however, you can define custom [script filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-script-query.html) for the same purpose. For example, lets assume that you've defined the following script field:

```
{
  "script_fields" : {
    "some_date_fld_year":"doc["some_date_fld"].empty ? null : doc["some_date_fld"].date.year"
  }
}
```

you can filter by it with

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": " (doc["some_date_fld"].empty ? null : doc["some_date_fld"].date.year) >= 2017",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. any idea if this is available in 6.7?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)